# Mandelbrot message queue blocking - C

Tags: c, message-queue, mandelbrot

I'm having problems in using message queues in this program
it is supposed to launch a number of processes that is passed by argument to the program by the command prompt but it only launches and calculates the points for one process... the others don't get to launch ..
Please help me .

This is the program that creates the message queues and outputs the selected data into pgm format
only the first process gets to run the other processes don't
can anybody tell me why ?

```
 #include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void output_pgm(char *filename,double *buffer, int nx, int ny, double max) {
  int i;
  FILE *file;
  file = fopen(filename,"w");
  fprintf(file,"P2\n");
  fprintf(file,"%d %d\n",nx,ny);
  fprintf(file,"%d\n",(int)max);
  for (i=0; i<nx*ny; i++) {
    if (!(i%nx)) fprintf(file,"\n");
    fprintf(file,"%d ",(int)buffer[i]);
  }
  fclose(file);
}

void main(int argc,char *argv[]) {

    if(argc != 2) {
    } else {

       int n = atoi(argv[1]);
       int i = 0;
       struct msgbuf {
              long mtype;
        int x;
        int y;
        double value;
       };

       struct envio {
          long mtype;
          long type;
          int ny;
          double yM1;
          double yM2;
       };


        key_t key = 123;
        key_t key2 = 124;
        int msgflg = IPC_CREAT | 0666;
        int msqid = msgget(key,msgflg);
        int msqid2 = msgget(key2,msgflg);
       switch(fork()) {
           case -1:
            printf("Erro de fork");
            break;
           case 0:
            printf("Oi: %d\n",n);           
            double *b;
            int x,y,i,m;

            double *ptr = b = malloc(1000*1000*sizeof(double));
            printf("Chego(1)\n");
                struct msgbuf a;
            struct envio c;
            size_t buflen = sizeof(a) - sizeof(long);
            size_t len2 = sizeof(c) - sizeof(long);
            printf("Chego(2)\n");
            int msid = msgget(key,msgflg);
            int msid2 = msgget(key2,msgflg);
            printf("Chego(3)\n");           
            double aux = -1.0;
            double multiplier = ((1.0/n) * 2);
            c.mtype = 300;
            int ny = (int)(1000/n);

            for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
             c.type = (i+1);
               c.ny = (int)(1000/n);
               c.yM1 = aux;
               c.yM2 = aux+multiplier;
               printf("Chego aqui(2)\n");
                           if(msgsnd(msid2,&c,len2,0) < 0) {
                  perror("Erro do 1o envio\n");
               }
            }
        for(m = 0; m < n; m++) {
               printf("Entrei no ciclo(1)\n");

            for(y = 0; y <ny ;y++) {
                //printf("Chego(4)\n");
                 for(x = 0; x < 1000;x++) {
                if(msgrcv(msid,&a,buflen,(long)(m+1),0) < 0) {
                   perror("Erro na recepcao:\n ");       
                }
                //printf("Chego(5)\n");
                b[a.y * ny + a.x] = a.value;
                 }
            }

            b = b + (1000/n)*1000;
           }
            output_pgm("mandel.pgm", ptr, 1000, 1000, 255);
            //msgctl(msid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
            //msgctl(msid2, IPC_RMID, NULL);
            printf("Processo 1\n");
            break;
           default:
             for(i = 0;i < n;i++) {
              switch(fork()) {
                  case -1:
                   printf("Erro de fork");
                case 0:
                   exit(0);
                   break;
                default:
                    printf("Fui lancado\n");
                    execlp("/home/hyper/Documents/SO2/TP3-4/rec","rec",0);
                    break;
              }
                 }
             break;         
        }             
    }   

};
```

The for loop in this program is run only once

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/msg.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
double type;
       struct senbuf {
              long mtype;
        int x;
        int y;
        double value;
       };
int max_iterations = 256;

double compute_point(double ci, double cr) {
  int iterations = 0;
  double zi = 0;
  double zr = 0;

  while ((zr*zr + zi*zi < 4) && (iterations < max_iterations)) {
    double nr, ni;

    /* Z <-- Z^2 + C */

    nr = zr*zr - zi*zi + cr;
    ni = 2*zr*zi + ci;

    zi = ni;
    zr = nr;

    iterations ++;
  } 
  return iterations; 
}

/* The "compute" function computes the Mandelbrot function over every
   point on a grid that is "nx" points wide by "ny" points tall, where
   (xmin,ymin) and (xmax,ymax) give two corners of the region the
   complex plane.
*/

void compute(int msqid,int nx, int ny, double xmin, double xmax,
         double ymin, double ymax,long type2 ) {

  double delta_x, delta_y;
  int x, y;
  struct senbuf sen;
  delta_x = (xmax - xmin)/nx;
  delta_y = (ymax - ymin)/ny;
  size_t buflen = sizeof(sen) - sizeof(long);
  for (y=0;  y<ny; y++) {
    //printf("Ja entrei aqui");
    double y_value = ymin + delta_y * y;
    for (x=0; x<nx; x++) {
      double x_value = xmin + delta_x * x;
      sen.mtype = type;
      sen.x = x;
      sen.y = y;
      sen.value = compute_point(x_value,y_value);
      if(msgsnd(msqid,&sen,buflen,0) < 0) {
        perror("Erro no envio:");
      };     
     // printf("%f",sen.a[y*nx + x]);
      //buffer[y*nx + x] = compute_point(x_value, y_value);
    }
  }
   printf("Ja mandei %d\n",type2);  
/*sen.mtype=500;
   sen.test = -1;
   printf("Ja to a sair\n");
   msgsnd(msqid,&sen,buflen,IPC_NOWAIT);*/
}

/* Output the data contained in the buffer to a Portable Greymap format
   image file.  The parameter "max" should be an upper bound for the
   data values in the buffer.
*/

void output_pgm(char *filename,double *buffer, int nx, int ny, double max) {
  int i;
  FILE *file;
  file = fopen(filename,"w");
  fprintf(file,"P2\n");
  fprintf(file,"%d %d\n",nx,ny);
  fprintf(file,"%d\n",(int)max);
  for (i=0; i<nx*ny; i++) {
    if (!(i%nx)) fprintf(file,"\n");
    fprintf(file,"%d ",(int)buffer[i]);
  }
  fclose(file);
}

int main()
{
    int msqid;
    int msqid2;
          struct recep {
          long mtype;
          long type;
          int ny;
          double yM1;
          double yM2;
       };

     struct recep a;
     size_t len = sizeof(a) - sizeof(long);
     key_t key = 124;
     msqid = msgget(key, 0666);
     if(msgrcv(msqid, &a, len, 300, 0) < 0) {
          perror("Error checking");
     };
    printf("Dados :\n Tipo : %d\n Ny: %d\n,yM1 : %f\n yM2: %f\n",a.type,a.ny,a.yM1,a.yM2);


     type = a.type;
     printf("Vou iniciar o compute");

     key_t key2 = 123;
         msqid2 = msgget(key2,0666);    
     compute(msqid2,1000,a.ny, -1.0, 1.0,a.yM1,a.yM2,a.type);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first switch statement you create one child doing whatever it is doing.  The parent falls into a second switch statement in which the child immediately exits and the parent is overlaid with the "rec" executable.  The parent no longer executes at point - it is the program "rec".  You are never going to execute more than one pass of the loop because the code that is executing is gone at that point.  If you want multiple instances of "rec" running you should be using `execlp` on the children not the parent.

**EDIT**

There are two system calls `wait` and `waitpid` that provides various options.  The simpler of these is `wait` and should be sufficient for what you are doing.  Define and increment a counter in the parent for each child you create.  Then instead of just exiting the parent you wait for all the children to finish.  Something as simple as this should suffice:

```
for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
{
    wait(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Yes I have put the execlp on the child should I put the exit(0) on the parent ?

Comment: You could exit the parent but it would probably be better to `wait` on the children.

Comment: Hello can you please show me how I can wait on the children ?